# Is the file mode flag “ios::app” used to delete a file if it already exists?

Tags: c++

I had this question in mind about the file mode flag `ios::app`. Is it used to delete a file if it already exists?

Comment: Try [this site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the flag `std::ios::app` isn't used to delete a file if already exists.

When `std::ios::app` flag is set, all output operations are performed at the end of the file.

Rather you could use to delete a file if exists (you must have `filesystem` library which exists in `c++17` and above):

```
try {
    if (std::filesystem::remove("file.txt"))
        std::cout << "file deleted.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "file not found.\n";

} catch (const std::filesystem::filesystem_error &err) {
    std::cout << "FS error: " << err.what() << '\n';
}
```